# Why JDBC authentication failing with CORS in spring boot and react?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security

I am trying to login using JDBC authentication using spring security in backend and react in frontend. I added CORS filter in spring security configuration but even with right username and password i am getting error wrong username password. Login was working fine in jsp. i disabled csrf check using `.csrf().disable()`.

this is how network log of post request

[image]

this is response i am getting from server

[image]

i added global CORS configuration as follows

**AppConfig.java**

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan(basePackages = { "net.kzn.onlineshopping.*", 
"net.kzn.shoppingbackend.*" })
public class AppConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {
@Override
public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
    registry.addMapping("/**")
    .allowedMethods("HEAD", "GET", "PUT", "POST", "DELETE", "PATCH");
}
}
```

filter configuration for cors as follows 
**SecurityConfig.java**

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

@Autowired DataSource dataSource;

@Autowired
private BCryptPasswordEncoder bCryptPasswordEncoder;
 @Override
    public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
        web.ignoring().antMatchers("/resources/**");
    }

@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
    .cors()
        .and()
        .csrf().disable()   
        .authorizeRequests()                                                                
            .antMatchers("/**").permitAll()                  
            .antMatchers("/manage/**").hasRole("ADMIN")                                      
            .antMatchers("/cart/**").hasRole("USER")            
            .anyRequest().authenticated()                                                   
            .and()
        .formLogin()
            .loginPage("/login")
            .permitAll()
            .and()
            .logout()
            .permitAll()
            .and()
        .exceptionHandling()
            .accessDeniedPage("/access-denied")
        .and()
            .httpBasic();

}

@Bean
public CorsConfigurationSource corsConfigurationSource() {
    CorsConfiguration configuration = new CorsConfiguration();
    configuration.setAllowedOrigins(Arrays.asList("*"));
    configuration.setAllowedMethods(Arrays.asList("GET", "POST", "PUT", "PATCH", "DELETE", "OPTIONS"));
    configuration.setAllowCredentials(true);
    configuration.setAllowedHeaders(Arrays.asList("authorization", "Cache-Control", "content-type", "x-auth-token", "JDBC"));
    UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
    source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", configuration);
    return source;
}

@Override
public void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    auth
        .jdbcAuthentication()
        .usersByUsernameQuery("select email, password, enabled from user_detail where email = ?")
        .authoritiesByUsernameQuery("select email, role from user_detail where email = ?")
        .dataSource(dataSource)
        .passwordEncoder(bCryptPasswordEncoder);
     System.out.println("inside security config");
}

}
```

**controller.java**

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/login")
public Map<String, Object> login(
        @RequestParam(name = "error", required = false) String error,
        @RequestParam(name = "logout", required = false) String logout) {
    Map<String, Object> login = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    System.out.println("Login..");
    login.put("title", "Login");
    if (error != null) { 
        login.put("message", "Username and Password is invalid!");
    }
    if (logout != null) {
        login.put("logout", "You have logged out successfully!");
    }
    return login; 
}
```

Even with right username password why i am getting error? Am i missing any configuration here? please help me.

Comment: There’s no CORS error shown in the question. Instead the response details show in the screenshot seem to indicate the server CORS config is working as expected.

Comment: as @dur said, change the content type to application/x-www-form-urlencoded

Comment: after adding application/x-www-form-urlencoded I logged in successfully. Thanks for help.

Comment: Please add code, errors and data as **text** ([using code formatting](//stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code)), not images. Images: A) don't allow us to copy-&-paste the code/errors/data for testing; B) don't permit searching based on the code/error/data contents; and [many more reasons](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557). In general, code/errors/data in text format >>>> code/errors/data as an image >> nothing.  Images should only be used, *in addition to text in code format*, if having the image adds something significant that is not conveyed by just the text code/error/data.

Comment: @Makyen ok i will keep that in mind.

Answer (score 2):

After adding application/x-www-form-urlencoded in my axios request my problem solved.

```
export const addProjectTask = (username,password, history) => async dispatch => {

axios.post('http://localhost:8080/onlineshopping/login', 
   Qs.stringify({
    username: username,
    password: password
    }), {
    headers: { 
      "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
    }})
  .then(function (response) {
    console.log(response);
    history.push("/");  
  })
  .catch(function (error) {
    console.log(error);
  });

  };
```